# How to match and copy everything up to first occurrence of a character using regex?

Tags: regex

Sample text format:

```
tom@yahoo.com,age:30|http://....
tom1@yahoo.com,age:31|http://....
tom2@yahoo.com,age:32|http://....
```

I want to match and copy everything before the '|'.
My regex: `^[^|]+`
this will match everything up to the '|', how can I copy all the occurrences?

2nd question
Sample text format:

```
tom@yahoo.com,age:30|100 lb
tom1@yahoo.com,age:31|200 lb
tom2@yahoo.com,age:32|300 lb
```

how can I match and copy all the text and range of 200 lb and below. So the first two line should be extracted and copied.

Comment: Depending on the environment/language/tool you use, there are better tools than `regex` for both tasks.

Comment: what do you suggest

Comment: @DifferentialEquations `split("|")` method is classic for your cause

Comment: @DifferentialEquations put in the question and/or tag it with the language or the tool you use to process the text. Without this information the question is too broad and the *"copy all the occurrences"* part cannot be answered.

Comment: @axiac I just paste the text on notepad++

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**:

1. `(?m)^[^|]+`
2. `(?m)^[^|]+\|\b(?:[1]?[0-9][0-9]?|200)\slb\b` or `(?m)^[^|]+\|\b(?:1?\d\d?|200)\slb\b`

**Details**:

- `(?m)` Multi line
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `[^]` Match a single character not present in the list
- `|` or
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
- `?` Matches between zero and one times
- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `\s` Matches any whitespace character

[Regex demo 1. Question](https://regex101.com/r/OvynsI/1)

[Regex demo 2. Question](https://regex101.com/r/OvynsI/5)

Comment: Thanks, this only matches the occurrences, how can I copy them all